react-leaflet: missing touchstart event
I would like to handle touchstart and touchend events on the react-leaflet map component but seem to be unable to do so - what am I missing?
Here's what I tried - general setup:
<MapContainer>
  <MapInitializer />
  ...
</MapContainer>


Handle events using a map initializer component

function MapInitializer() {
  const map = useMap();

  const handleTouchStart = (event) => {
    alert('DEBUG touchstart 1');
  }

  map.on('touchstart', handleTouchStart);
}


With useMapEvent as per the docs

function MapInitializer() {
  const map2 = useMapEvent('touchstart', () => {
    alert('DEBUG touchstart 2');
  });
}


Directly on the map component

<MapContainer touchStart='handleTouchStart'>
  ...
</MapContainer>

